# Read values from another cell in IPython Notebook and supply them for "input()"

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

As an example, if I have a cell that looks like:

```
In [*]: for i in range(int(input())):
            print(i**2)
```

When the cell is run, an input box pops up and waits for input to be provided. Is there a Built-in magic command or any way to programmatically supply values when `input()` is encountered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write this as an answer, although this is more or less a comment.

One "hacky" way is to overwrite `input` or make a generator which returns an input-function with a constant return value. So kind of mocking it…

```
def input_generator(return_value):
    def input():
        return return_value
    return input
```

This will work as:

```
>> input = input_generator(42)
>> input()
42
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping there was a way that i could not clobber the input() built-in, rather decorate the cell or something.

Comment: Hmm I don't know about decorating an IPython cell but in fact it should be the same procedure. You setup an overwritten input and then restore it…